# Gmail removes in-line CSS

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I've been having problems with gaps in-between my images on HTML emails I've been creating. I've learnt from guides online that using display: block on img tags works as an easy fix. However it seems gmail now removes all in-line CSS.

I use Chrome browser. I have also tested this in Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE. The issue is the same for all of them.

This also effects the issue with line-height on td tags. Some gaps were known to be caused by line-height issues and previously in-line css was a solution. Now, however, I can't write css in-line or embedded to override what gmail applies.

Does anyone know of a current work-around or solution?

For example, the following does not work on gmail using Chrome - the css is removed by gmail:

```
<table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="592">
    <tbody style="line-height:0px;padding:0;margin:0;" width="700" height="592">
    <tr width="700" height="296">
        <td style="line-height:0px;" width="441" height="296">
            <a href="[the url]" target="_blank" width="441" height="296">
                <img src="[the url]" style="display:block;border:0;" width="441" alt="[the alt text]" height="296"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="line-height:0px;" width="39" height="296">
            <img src="[the url]" style="display:block;border:0;" width="39" height="296"/>
        </td>
        <td style="line-height:0px;" width="220" height="296">
            <a href="[the url]" target="_blank" width="220" height="296">
                <img src="[the url]" style="display:block;border:0;" width="220" alt="[the alt text]" height="296"/>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="line-height:0px;" width="700" height="296">
        <td style="line-height: 0px;" width="441" height="296">
            <a href="[the url]" target="_blank" width="441" height="296">
                <img src="[the url]" style="display:block;border:0;" width="441" alt="[the alt text]" height="296"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="line-height:0px;" width="39" height="296">
            <img src="[the url]" style="display:block;border:0;" width="39" height="296"/>
        </td>
        <td style="line-height:0px;" width="220" height="296">
            <a href="[the url]" target="_blank" height="296">
                <img src="[the url]" style="display:block;border:0;" width="220" alt="[the alt text]" height="296">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PS - I'm aware some of the tags don't need those attributes - I've added them for testing purposes to be exhaustive and to ensure as much has been declared as possible.

Comment: from which client did you sent the test email?

Comment: @afelixj yes, sorry, should have said. I use Chrome.

Comment: @afelixj I have also tested this in Safari, Opera, Firefox and IE. The issue is the same in all of them.

Comment: Not the browser.. From where do you send the mail to your gmail ?

Comment: @afelixj our testing application sends us an email which we open and forward (to our gmail account) using Microsoft Outlook 2007 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the testing application or outlook may be trimming the inline style.

Please try `align:left` also instead of `display:block`.

Comment: You were correct - we discovered that when forwarding an email from Outlook, the rendering engine it uses (Microsoft Word !) messes with inline styles. When the email was sent directly to the web based email client it was fine.